# Mongoose: Using aggregate to filter based on Model.field_1.field_2 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mern

I have this function:

```
const getNotificationsForLounge = async (lounge_id) => {
  try {
    const notifications = await Notification.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          "lounge_join_request.lounge": lounge_id,
          lounge_join_request: { $ne: null },
        },
      },
    ]);
    console.log(" ~ notifications:", notifications);
    // Do something with the notifications
    return notifications;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(" ~ error:", error);
    // Handle the error
  }
};
```

I feed it a `lounge_id` and it searchs the notifications where `notification.lounge_join_request.lounge` is equal that `lounge_id`.

I wrote a second function that pulls a random `notification` and gets its `lounge_join_request.lounge_id` and then feeds that `lounge_id` to the first function.

```
const getNotificationWithRandomLoungeJoinRequest = async () => {
  try {
    const notification = await Notification.aggregate([
      // Match notifications with lounge join requests
      {
        $match: {
          category: "LOUNGE_JOIN_REQUEST",
          lounge_join_request: { $ne: null },
        },
      },
      // Select a random notification using $sample
      { $sample: { size: 1 } },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "lounge_join_requests",
          localField: "lounge_join_request",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "lounge_join_request",
        },
      },
      // Project the lounge ID
      { $project: { _id: 0, lounge_id: "$lounge_join_request.lounge" } },
    ]);
    const lounge_id = notification[0].lounge_id[0];
    // Logs a lounge id
    //  ~ file: loungeServices.js:663 ~ getNotificationWithRandomLoungeJoinRequest ~ lounge_id: 63ef344xxxxb4943355
    // Which means there exists a notification
    // Where notification.lounge_join_request.lounge equals this lounge_id
    console.log(
      " ~ file: loungeServices.js:663 ~ getNotificationWithRandomLoungeJoinRequest ~ lounge_id:",
      lounge_id
    );

    // But, when I feed that lounge_id into this function
    // Which searchs notifications where
    // notification.lounge_join_request.lounge equals this lounge_id
    // It logs an empty array
    return await getNotificationsForLounge(lounge_id);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(" ~ error:", error);
  }
};
```

Since, I pulled that `lounge_id` from an existing `notification`. The first function should at least return an array containing that notification.

But, it doesn't, it always returns an **empty array**. Focus on this part:

```
 const lounge_id = notification[0].lounge_id[0];
    // Logs a lounge id
    //  ~ file: loungeServices.js:663 ~ getNotificationWithRandomLoungeJoinRequest ~ lounge_id: 63ef344xxxxb4943355
    // Which means there exists a notification
    // Where notification.lounge_join_request.lounge equals this lounge_id
    console.log(
      " ~ file: loungeServices.js:663 ~ getNotificationWithRandomLoungeJoinRequest ~ lounge_id:",
      lounge_id
    );

    // But, when I feed that lounge_id into this function
    // Which searchs notifications where
    // notification.lounge_join_request.lounge equals this lounge_id
    // It logs an empty array
    return await getNotificationsForLounge(lounge_id);
```

Any idea why?

---

These are the relevant models:

> Notification.js

```
const NotificationSchema = new Schema({
  lounge_join_request: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "lounge_join_requests",
    default: null,
  },
});

module.exports = Notification = mongoose.model(
  "notification",
  NotificationSchema
);
```

> LoungeJoinRequest.js

```
const LoungeJoinRequestSchema = new Schema({
  lounge: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "lounge",
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = LoungeJoinRequest = mongoose.model(
  "lounge_join_requests",
  LoungeJoinRequestSchema
);
```

> Lounge.js

```
const LoungeSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
    },
  }
);

module.exports = Channel = mongoose.model("lounge", LoungeSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your schema the `lounge_join_request` field contains an ObjectId, not an object, so there is no `lounge_join_request.lounge` field to match against.

If `lounge_id` contains a match for the `_id` of the lounge join request document, you can match with

```
 {
     $match: {
        lounge_join_request: lounge_id,
        lounge_join_request: { $ne: null },
     },
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand why are you matching lounge_join_request with lounge_id when each of these refer to different schemas.

Comment: Mongoose, including its schemas, only exist on the client side, while the aggregation pipeline will be executed on the database server.  The `lounge_id` here is a javascript variable whose value will be substitued into the pipeline before sending to the server, and `lounge_join_request` is the field name defined in the notification schema.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have mentioned, I think problem is not there. Because first aggregation does return a result if you have `lounge` attribute set in `lounge_join_requests` collection. You can check it in here [Mongo Playground Snippet](https://mongoplayground.net/p/naQeElYYNdT)

I think problem is in your `getNotificationsForLounge` method. As you are trying to find notification by `lounge_id` and that `lounge_id` is for `lounge` collection. `notification` collection has no relation with `lounge` collection. So, finding by `lounge_id` from `lounge` collection will do no help.

If you need to do so then you can try `getNotificationsForLounge` like this -

```
const getNotificationsForLounge = async (lounge_id) => {
  try {
    const notifications = await Notification.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "lounge_join_requests",
          localField: "lounge_join_request",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "lounge_join_request",
        },
      },
      {
        $match: {
          "lounge_join_request.lounge": lounge_id,
          "lounge_join_request": { $ne: null },
        },
      }
    ]);
    console.log(" ~ notifications:", notifications);
    // Do something with the notifications
    return notifications;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(" ~ error:", error);
    // Handle the error
  }
};
```

Hopefully this work. Let me know in the comment.